# QEmu error --- when running executable

Tags: wxwidgets, raspberry-pi, qemu

I have cross compiled my project in scratchbox, it uses :---
1> WX-widget base class (i.e uses socket, thread, string related classes..... no GUI stuff)  (http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
2> Libwebsocket (http://libwebsockets.org/trac)

Compilation is successfull without error. Target is Debian Weezy & Processor is Raspberry pi.

Scratchbox uses QEmu for running cross executables.
When i run executable under sb2( scratchbox ). I get following error

```
x$ sb2 -e vscpd
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Exit reason and status: signal 11 (core dumped)
```

----------------- Qemu GDB log ------------------------

```
ignite@ignite:~/sbox2/rootfs/rfs-raspbian/home/pi/vscp_software/src/vscp/daemon/linux$ sb2 -t rfs-raspbian -eR gdb vscpd
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/ignite/sbox2/rootfs/rfs-raspbian/home/pi/vscp_software/src/vscp/daemon/linux/vscpd...done.

===========================================================
Welcome to scratchbox2 enabled gdb!

Before starting target program you should run command
'sb2-prepare' that sets breakpoint which is used
to stop target before its main() gets called.  After
the breakpoint is hit, you are able to set furtherbreakpoints and do normal debugging actions.

If you are attaching to already running process or
examining a core dump, this step is not necessary.
===========================================================

(sb2-emulate-gdb) sb2-prepare 
Function "_dl_debug_state" not defined.
Temporary breakpoint 1 (_dl_debug_state) pending.
(sb2-emulate-gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ignite/sbox2/rootfs/rfs-raspbian/home/pi/vscp_software/src/vscp/daemon/linux/vscpd 
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 26
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 26
During startup program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(sb2-emulate-gdb)
```

Please suggest this error is because of what ?

//Katoch

Comment: It's going to be hard to guess without more details. You should get a backtrace with gdb, follow a guide like [this one](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace) or equivalent that applies to the distro you're running on the **host**.

Comment: My target is Raspberry pi which have ---- arm vfb
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi

Can i run this application on my intel Host?

Comment: Aren't you running qemu on your host to emulate ARM, and qemu is what crashes? If so you need to debug qemu just like any other x86 program.

Comment: @dequis i have added GDB log . Please suggest on it.

Comment: Hmmm you're missing a backtrace, but I think this gdb debugs your app instead of qemu which is what's actually crashing. Not sure. Try typing "bt" and if it gives anything useful include it.

Comment: bt command gives out put No stack ..... fyi Qemu is installed inside scratchbox folder. And scratchboxuses QEmu to run cross application.

Comment: $ file rpi_exp 
rpi_exp: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.6.3, not stripped ---------
$ sb2 -e rpi_exp 
Hello, world!

Comment: i was able to run a simple application program -- hello world --- cross executable.. rpi_exp  --- as shown above.

Comment: should i use Qemu version  ---  'cvs-m' version of qemu   ----> as per these links -----  http://talk.maemo.org/archive/index.php/t-24039.html   -------------
http://blogs.kde.org/2008/09/09/having-fun-qemu

Comment: What is actually happening ----->
Is my application is crashing or Qemu is crashing ?

Comment: Qemu is, but I have no experience with scratchbox to know how to debug that instead of the app. Those posts you linked are really old and if there's more stable code it should be merged already.